# Laravel 5 Response json and input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is the Laravel 5 equivelant for Laravel 4s?:

```
Response::json
Response::input
```

And what facade do I need to use?

Answer (score 2):

Inject the `ResponseFactory` into your class/method:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory;

class SomeClass {

    protected $response;

    public function __construct(ResponseFactory $response)
    {
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        return $this->response->json($data);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
// This will only work if method is resolved by service container
public function someMethod(ResponseFactory $response)
{
    return $response->json($data);
}
```

You can find a map of Laravel façades and what to type-hint instead at http://laravel.com/docs/master/facades#facade-class-reference

Alternative, you *can* still use façades, you just need to import them:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Response;

class SomeClass {

    public function someMethod()
    {
        return Response::json($data);
    }
}
```

But I’d recommend going the injecting-contracts routes. It’s just a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

`Response::json()` ----> `response()->json(['key'=>'value'])`

laravel 4.2 way works too btw.

`Response::input()` (?) [input should be in request] ----> `Request::input()`

here also, you can `Input` facade. In practice, not much changed in L5 as long as facades are concerned.